# How can I parse this as an object or array with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

When I call this url: `https://dogsatmyjob.tumblr.com/api/read/json?id=165570102911`

I get a string response like this:

```
var tumblr_api_read = {"tumblelog":{"title":"Dogs At My Job","description":"<p>Just a simple collection of the pups that I see everyday at my dog care job.<\/p>","name":"dogsatmyjob","timezone":"US\/Mountain","cname":false,"feeds":[]},"posts-start":0,"posts-total":1359,"posts-type":false,"posts":[{"id":"165570102911","url":"https:\/\/dogsatmyjob.tumblr.com\/post\/165570102911","url-with-slug":"https:\/\/dogsatmyjob.tumblr.com\/post\/165570102911\/dogsatmyjob-catcher-is-always-camera-ready","type":"photo","date-gmt":"2017-09-21 04:00:40 GMT","date":"Wed, 20 Sep 2017 22:00:40","bookmarklet":0,"mobile":0,"feed-item":"","from-feed-id":0,"unix-timestamp":1505966440,"format":"html","reblog-key":"FpmqGk7D","slug":"dogsatmyjob-catcher-is-always-camera-ready","is-submission":false,"like-button":"<div class=\"like_button\" data-post-id=\"165570102911\" data-blog-name=\"dogsatmyjob\" id=\"like_button_165570102911\"><iframe id=\"like_iframe_165570102911\" src=\"https:\/\/assets.tumblr.com\/assets\/html\/like_iframe.html?_v=66c22ab5319d742bca5762b8d18f9d06#name=dogsatmyjob&amp;post_id=165570102911&amp;color=black&amp;rk=FpmqGk7D&amp;root_id=159690206439\" scrolling=\"no\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\" frameborder=\"0\" class=\"like_toggle\" allowTransparency=\"true\" name=\"like_iframe_165570102911\"><\/iframe><\/div>","reblog-button":"<a href=\"https:\/\/www.tumblr.com\/reblog\/165570102911\/FpmqGk7D\" class=\"reblog_button\"style=\"display: block;width:20px;height:20px;\"><svg width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" viewBox=\"0 0 21 21\" xmlns=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2000\/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/1999\/xlink\" fill=\"#000\"><path d=\"M5.01092527,5.99908429 L16.0088498,5.99908429 L16.136,9.508 L20.836,4.752 L16.136,0.083 L16.1360004,3.01110845 L2.09985349,3.01110845 C1.50585349,3.01110845 0.979248041,3.44726568 0.979248041,4.45007306 L0.979248041,10.9999998 L3.98376463,8.30993634 L3.98376463,6.89801007 C3.98376463,6.20867902 4.71892527,5.99908429 5.01092527,5.99908429 Z\"><\/path><path d=\"M17.1420002,13.2800293 C17.1420002,13.5720293 17.022957,14.0490723 16.730957,14.0490723 L4.92919922,14.0490723 L4.92919922,11 L0.5,15.806 L4.92919922,20.5103758 L5.00469971,16.9990234 L18.9700928,16.9990234 C19.5640928,16.9990234 19.9453125,16.4010001 19.9453125,15.8060001 L19.9453125,9.5324707 L17.142,12.203\"><\/path><\/svg><\/a>","state":"published","note-count":"219","reblogged-from-url":"https:\/\/dogsatmyjob.tumblr.com\/post\/159690206439\/catcher-is-always-camera-ready","reblogged-from-name":"dogsatmyjob","reblogged-from-title":"Dogs At My Job","reblogged_from_avatar_url_512":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_512.png","reblogged_from_avatar_url_128":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_128.png","reblogged_from_avatar_url_96":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_96.png","reblogged_from_avatar_url_64":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_64.png","reblogged_from_avatar_url_48":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_48.png","reblogged_from_avatar_url_40":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_40.png","reblogged_from_avatar_url_30":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_30.png","reblogged_from_avatar_url_24":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_24.png","reblogged_from_avatar_url_16":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_16.png","reblogged-root-url":"https:\/\/dogsatmyjob.tumblr.com\/post\/159690206439\/catcher-is-always-camera-ready","reblogged-root-name":"dogsatmyjob","reblogged-root-title":"Dogs At My Job","reblogged_root_avatar_url_512":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_512.png","reblogged_root_avatar_url_128":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_128.png","reblogged_root_avatar_url_96":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_96.png","reblogged_root_avatar_url_64":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_64.png","reblogged_root_avatar_url_48":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_48.png","reblogged_root_avatar_url_40":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_40.png","reblogged_root_avatar_url_30":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_30.png","reblogged_root_avatar_url_24":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_24.png","reblogged_root_avatar_url_16":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_16.png","tumblelog":{"title":"Dogs At My Job","name":"dogsatmyjob","cname":false,"url":"https:\/\/dogsatmyjob.tumblr.com\/","timezone":"US\/Mountain","avatar_url_512":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_512.png","avatar_url_128":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_128.png","avatar_url_96":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_96.png","avatar_url_64":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_64.png","avatar_url_48":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_48.png","avatar_url_40":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_40.png","avatar_url_30":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_30.png","avatar_url_24":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_24.png","avatar_url_16":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/avatar_89ca7a2e202d_16.png"},"photo-caption":"<p><a href=\"https:\/\/dogsatmyjob.tumblr.com\/post\/159690206439\/catcher-is-always-camera-ready\" class=\"tumblr_blog\">dogsatmyjob<\/a>:<\/p>\n\n<blockquote><p>Catcher is always camera-ready.<\/p><\/blockquote>","width":960,"height":1280,"photo-url-1280":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/cac87bd90ea04d2ed28194aed7a79308\/tumblr_oojzetRpQD1w71lqmo1_1280.jpg","photo-url-500":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/cac87bd90ea04d2ed28194aed7a79308\/tumblr_oojzetRpQD1w71lqmo1_500.jpg","photo-url-400":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/cac87bd90ea04d2ed28194aed7a79308\/tumblr_oojzetRpQD1w71lqmo1_400.jpg","photo-url-250":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/cac87bd90ea04d2ed28194aed7a79308\/tumblr_oojzetRpQD1w71lqmo1_250.jpg","photo-url-100":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/cac87bd90ea04d2ed28194aed7a79308\/tumblr_oojzetRpQD1w71lqmo1_100.jpg","photo-url-75":"https:\/\/66.media.tumblr.com\/cac87bd90ea04d2ed28194aed7a79308\/tumblr_oojzetRpQD1w71lqmo1_75sq.jpg","photos":[],"tags":["catcher","german shepherd","germanshepherd","cute","adorable","beautiful","dog","dogs","puppy","puppies","dogsatmyjob","dogblr"]}]};
```

The thing is that this is a string of an asignment of a json body. Not just that, the `/` are shown as `\/`, so I would need to parse it but also escape these characters.

What would be the best way of parsing this so I can treat it as an object / array ?

Comment: My best bet would be to just use `response.body.replace("var tumblr_api_read = ", "")` and then pop the last `;` character and then using `JSON.parse()` ? I wanted to find a better solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API documentation expects you to access a URL like that as the source of a `<script>` tag. That way the code returned will create the `tumblr_api_read` global variable.

What you could do when reading via an xhr would be to make a Function instance from it with an additional `return` statement:

```
var tumblrObject = new Function(responseString + " return tumblr_api_read;")();
```

Alternatively, you could chop off the trailing semicolon and the `var` declaration with some string hackery and then pass what's left to `JSON.parse()`. The backslashes before the slashes won't cause a problem; that's actually part of the JSON standard.

I should add that using the `new Function()` approach would introduce a risk. If tumblr.com is hacked, the API could return code that attempted to do bad things. That risk is present when using the `<script>` tag approach too. Modifying the string and using `JSON.parse()` is probably preferable from that standpoint.

Comment: If I understood it correctly, the variable returned within the context of a function then it can be returned when invoked. Awesome sir, thanks. It works.